# ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] during W&B hyperparameter search

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, hyperparameters, wandb

I am trying to do hyperparameter seach using Weights & Biases. Tried to run this code from documentation https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/sweeps/add-w-and-b-to-your-code in the notebook:

```
import wandb
import numpy as np 
import random

# Define sweep config
sweep_configuration = {
    'method': 'random',
    'name': 'sweep',
    'metric': {'goal': 'maximize', 'name': 'val_acc'},
    'parameters': 
    {
        'batch_size': {'values': [16, 32, 64]},
        'epochs': {'values': [5, 10, 15]},
        'lr': {'max': 0.1, 'min': 0.0001}
    }
 }

 # Initialize sweep by passing in config. 
 # (Optional) Provide a name of the project.
 sweep_id = wandb.sweep(
 sweep=sweep_configuration, 
     project='my-first-sweep'
 )

 # Define training function that takes in hyperparameter 
 # values from `wandb.config` and uses them to train a 
 # model and return metric
 def train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs): 
     acc = 0.25 + ((epoch/30) +  (random.random()/10))
     loss = 0.2 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/5))
     return acc, loss

 def evaluate_one_epoch(epoch): 
     acc = 0.1 + ((epoch/20) +  (random.random()/10))
     loss = 0.25 + (1 - ((epoch-1)/10 +  random.random()/6))
     return acc, loss

 def main():
     run = wandb.init()

     # note that we define values from `wandb.config`  
     # instead of defining hard values
     lr  =  wandb.config.lr
     bs = wandb.config.batch_size
     epochs = wandb.config.epochs

     for epoch in np.arange(1, epochs):
         train_acc, train_loss = train_one_epoch(epoch, lr, bs)
         val_acc, val_loss = evaluate_one_epoch(epoch)

     wandb.log({
         'epoch': epoch, 
         'train_acc': train_acc,
         'train_loss': train_loss, 
         'val_acc': val_acc, 
         'val_loss': val_loss
     })

# Start sweep job.
wandb.agent(sweep_id, function=main, count=4)
```

Got error `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`. How it can be fixed? When I run it in the colab, everything worked fine.